# Church style lists: infinite type error when compiling but not interactively

Tags: haskell

I'm just starting to learn haskell and I'm trying to implement lists in a pure lambda calculus way (such as described in [the wikipedia page for Church encoding](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Church_boolean#Higher-order_function)).

The following function produces a "cannot construct the infinite type" at compile time. However, when I execute the code of the function interactively, it works. This is the code of the function:

```
showl l = isempty' l 0 (head' l)
```

And here is how I run it interactively (it works):

```
let l = (cons' 7 empty') in isempty' l 0 (head' l)
```

With the function `showl`, I want to get the first element of a list (not a haskell list, but a list as defined in Church encoding) if it is not empty, and 0 otherwise. In details, `isempty' l` returns a Church boolean, namely the function `\ a b -> a` if the list `l` is empty (True), and `\ a b -> b` otherwise (False). This way, if True, `showl` returns 0, and `(head' l)' otherwise (the first element of the list).

I suppose it's a problem with type inference, as suggested by the other questions about infinit type errors. But I don't see it, and since it works interactively, it must be fine... I'm confused.

Thanks

(the exact compiler output:

```
Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: t = t1 -> t -> t2
Probable cause: `isempty'' is applied to too many arguments
In the expression: isempty' l 0 (head' l)
In the definition of `showl': showl l = isempty' l 0 (head' l)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

and the functions I wrote to define Church style lists:

```
-- True and False
t a b = a
f a b = b

-- pairs
pair a b z = z a b
fst' p = p t
snd' p = p f

-- lists
empty' f x = x
isempty' l = l (\ a b -> f) t
cons' a l f x = f a (l f x)
head' l = l t 0
tail' l = fst' (l (\x p -> pair (snd' p) (cons' x (snd' p))) (pair empty' empty'))
```

)

Comment: Have you tried tacking explicit type declarations on all your functions? This usually leads to more useful compiler errors.

Comment: I doubt this will compile without explicit annotations, since your functions may need rank-2-types.

Comment: Ok, I'm working on declaring type explicitly. I'll update my post when I have some news.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the compiler is getting confused here. Given an explicit type signature for your function (using `Rank2Types`), it compiles nicely and works just fine.

```
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types #-}

type List a = forall b. (a -> b -> b) -> b -> b

showl :: Num a => List a -> a 
showl l = isempty' l 0 (head' l)
```

When running it interactively it works because the concrete types are available.

Comment: Thanks. So I've been reading about rankNtypes and rank2types, but I really don't understand what they're about. What is the difference between a rank1 and rank2 type?

Comment: @flagadabla: A rank 1 type can only have the `forall` in the outermost position, while higher ranked types can have the `forall` more deeply nested. This is useful when you want to require that a function argument is polymorphic. For example, a function like `foo f = f "hello" + f 2` can only work if the function `f` is polymorphic, so we have to give it a rank 2 type like `foo :: (forall a. a -> Int) -> Int`.

Comment: @flagadabla: As well as what hammar said, note that `forall`s behave much like additional arguments, in that they're right-associative and can be reordered freely as long as they're to the left of the type variable they quantify. So `forall a. a -> (forall b. b -> a)` is still a rank 1 type, because it can be reordered as `forall a b. a -> b -> a`. They also behave much like lambdas in a way; they bind variables in a scope extending as far to the right as possible.

Comment: (I tried to add this as an answer to format the code, but it got deleted!?) Did you get a version of this with explicit types to work?

I had some problems; for example,

   a = cons' "a" empty'
   at = tail' a
   :t at
   tail_a :: ([Char] -> a -> b) -> a -> a
   :t empty'
   empty' :: a -> b -> b

Types don't match. Also,

   ab = cons' "a" (cons' "b" empty')
   head' ab
   ERROR - Cannot infer instance
   *** Instance   : Num [Char]
   *** Expression : head' ab

Comment: @guthrie: Yes, answers are supposed to answer the question. If you have problems, you should ask a new question. Anyway, I [wrote a gist some time ago with explicitly typed Church lists](https://gist.github.com/1159246). Have a look at that.